# Qt qml MediaPlayer/Video reproduces only Sound (without Video)

Tags: qt, qml

I use the player in QML, installed the k-lite-codec package and tried to play the mp4 and avi video formats, but it does not play them, only the sound.
Why is this?
What's wrong?

After closing the application, I get this debug log:

```
D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x03DBE8CC, Refcount: 8. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03E35D18, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DBF780, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CE68C4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC56FC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC58D4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC5ACC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC5CC4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC6184, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC6734, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03DC6CE4, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live                         Object :     10 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
DXGI WARNING: Live Producer at 0x03D1C814, Refcount: 3. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x03D4DCA0, Refcount: 3. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live                         Object :      1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
```

Comment: I used the standard example, and my own code and results were the same.
Standard code an example: qmlvideo (multimedia)
or use in my own code: MediaPlayer and VideoOutput or Video (same)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned k-lite-codec, I assume that you are using Windows. Check if you can play it in Windows Media Player. If not (only sound), then you are missing the necessary codecs in your system.